# Is it Possible to create Client Web Part enum property dynamically?

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, properties

I am creating an **`SharePoint Hosted App`** using **`CSOM`** technology. I want to set the **`ClientWebPart`** Property dynamically.

I want to add `enum` property Dynamically. App will bring all the list name from my AppWeb and fill the values in the **`enum`** property of the **`ClientWebPart`**.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not, the enum is written in XML prior to deploy

Comment: Is there any other way to set properties of App dynamically?

Comment: I guess your app can have some own custom settings. But that is not at all OOTB, but something you would have to architect and develop yourself